# Reach JBoss EAP 6 server in local network from mobile app

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, java, jboss

I have a Java application running on JBoss EAP 6 which I can "hit" from mobile app on chrome using urls like: `127.0.0.1:8280/myAwesomeJavaApp/coolService` ... so when I package the app I am using urls like this

```
192.168.1.64:8280/myAwesomeJavaApp/coolService //this is not working

192.168.1.64 // this gets me to my localhost
```

(connected to WiFi (testing purposes))

I can access all other Apache web apps in my localhost , but can't consume JBoss EAP 6 services.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Start Jboss server with -b 0.0.0.0

```
./standalone.sh -b.0.0.0.0 //this binds server to all network interfaces
```